# Error installing IBM Rational Software Architect for MacOs

Tags: macos, rational-rsa

I'm able to successfully install RSA 9.6 on my MacBook, but when I try to start the application I get the following error written out into my log.  Any help would be gratefully welcomed

```
!SESSION Fri Jun 30 08:21:28 CDT 2017 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2017-06-30 08:21:28.394
!MESSAGE Could not find extension: com.ibm.cds
!SESSION 2017-06-30 08:21:28.353 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.ibm.rational.rsa.product.v90.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -clean -product com.ibm.rational.rsa.product.v90.ide

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-06-30 08:21:29.088
!MESSAGE Bundle com.ibm.cds not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2017-06-30 08:21:29.379
!MESSAGE Product com.ibm.rational.rsa.product.v90.ide could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-06-30 08:21:36.198
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this on https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=9ed43812-9c67-4fd5-921b-f7acb405e12b.  The short answer is edit the following file:

/Applications/IBM/SoftwareDeliveryPlatform/RSA.app/Contents/MacOS/ExecuteScript

And change the one line to specify v9.6 instead of 9.5.  I tried an earlier version of RSA (9.1) and it had a similar problem of pointing to 9.0.  Really sad because this is a very powerful tool.

Change $ECLIPSE_APP -product com.ibm.rational.rsa.product.v95.ide &
to $ECLIPSE_APP -product com.ibm.rational.rsa.product.v96.ide &

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=9ed43812-9c67-4fd5-921b-f7acb405e12b